# Plot points on a contour map PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, optimization, mathematical-optimization

> GRADIENT METHOD, by the way

I have programmed an optimization algorithm which given a function, an initial point and a bunch of other parameters it returns the path to the local minimizer (the points, x and y coordinates). So far so good. But numbers are easily interpreted when seen in a plot, so what I want is to plot something like that (the plot at the left):
[image]

My attempt:

```
from pylab import *
f = lambda x : x[0]**2+(1/4)*x[1]**3+(1/2)*x[0]*x[1]+(15/4)*x[0]-(9/16)*x[1]

x = np.linspace(-10,10)
y = np.linspace(-10,10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

im = imshow(f(np.array([X,Y])), cmap=cm.RdBu, extent=[-10,10,-10,10])
colorbar(im)

x_axis = [x_k[i][0] for i in range(0, len(x_k))]
y_axis = [x_k[i][1] for i in range(0, len(x_k))]

plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis, 'ro-')
plt.plot(x_k[0][0], x_k[0][1], 'bo')
```

x_k contains the coordinates found by my algorithm. I am not a profi in plotting, so this code is just pieces I found on the internet and  combined in one, but the result is wrong. I would really appreciate if you could help me! Thanks in advance

Comment: The plot on the left does not seem difficult, it is basically using a contour plot, and then a line plot. However, you should provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)